# Opening directory through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Intent that is supposed to open a directory using the default file application. However, when the file app launches, it doesn't navigate to my desired folder. Instead, it opens to the initial page, which happens to be the Download folder.

This is my current solution

```
override fun onOpenFileLocationPressed() {
    val filePath = context.getExternalFilesDir("lorem")?.absolutePath
    Timber.d(filePath) //-> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/me.segosambel.myapp/files/lorem
    val fileUri = Uri.parse(filePath)
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        setDataAndType(fileUri, "vnd.android.document/directory")
    }
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: ACTION_VIEW is not supposed to do such things.

Comment: And on Android 11+ certainly not in an app private directory. Files app will not browse to that either.

Comment: Sorry, it is possible using content scheme uri for directory.